# How to achieve all possible modifications to an array of arrays of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

I have a array of arrays of hashes like so:

```
initial_tasks_groups = [
  [{task: 'Cut Tree', score: 25}, {task: 'Walk Dog', score: 10}], 
  [{task: 'Clean House', score: 10}, {task: 'Wash Floor', score: 10}, {task: 'Call Uncle Ben', score: 15}],
  [{task: 'Wash Giraffe', score: 15}, {task: 'Burn House', score: 19}]
]
```

I call *swaping [sic] equivalent tasks* to be: An operation to replace one or more hashes in a subarray with one or more hashes in another subarray so that the sum of the `:score` values of the hashes is not changed.  For example, `'Walk dog'` task can be replaced by `'Clean House'` task (both have a score of 10). Or, `'Cut Tree'` (25) can be replaced by `'Walk Dog'` (10) and `'Call uncle Ben'` (15).

I call an *equivalent combination* to be an array created by swaping [sic] equivalent tasks in `initial_tasks_groups`.

My goal is to find all the possible equivalent combinations. The final result should be an array like the following:

```
all_possible_combinaisons = [
  initial_tasks_groups,
  [
    [{task: 'Cut Tree', score: 25}, {task: 'Clean House', score: 10}], 
    [{task: 'Walk Dog', score: 10}, {task: 'Wash Floor', score: 10}, {task: 'Call Uncle Ben', score: 15}],
    [{task: 'Wash Giraffe', score: 15}, {task: 'Burn House', score: 19}]
  ],
  [
    [{task: 'Cut Tree', score: 25}, {task: 'Clean House', score: 10}], 
    [{task: 'Walk Dog', score: 10}, {task: 'Wash Floor', score: 10}, {task: 'Wash Giraffe', score: 15}],
    [{task: 'Call Uncle Ben', score: 15}, {task: 'Burn House', score: 19}]
  ],
  ...
]
```

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: What is the _unclean_ way of doing it that you implemented?

Comment: I don't think there is a **clean** way as such. If you need a solution to achieve the same (**unclean way**), I can look into it.

Comment: Considering that `all_possible_combinaisons[2] =  initial_tasks_groups[2]`, why aren't all elements of `initial_tasks_groups` members of  `all_possible_combinaisons`? Your question is not clear. Also, when giving examples everything should be a Ruby object.  For one, no "etc."!

Comment: I am new to ruby (and stackoverflow), my apologies if the question is not clear. 
The "clean" part of the question was because I had something very messy and knew it couldn't be the right answer. 
@CarySwoveland, all_possible_combinaisons[2] is not equal to initial_tasks_groups[2] but I realise my question wasn't well formulated.

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively easy for a little to medium amount of tasks. First, let’s prepare some data from the initial array of hashes.

```
input = [
  [{task: 'Cut Tree', score: 25},
   {task: 'Walk Dog', score: 10}], 
  [{task: 'Clean House', score: 10},
   {task: 'Wash Floor', score: 10},
   {task: 'Call Uncle Ben', score: 15}],
  [{task: 'Wash Giraffe', score: 15},
   {task: 'Burn House', score: 19}]]
```

The goal is to shuffle tasks so that the score for each array remained the same. Hence, let’s start with collecting goals:

```
goals = input.map { |a| a.reduce(0) { |acc, h| acc + h[:score] } }
#⇒ [35, 35, 34]
```

Now let’s prepare the filter function:

```
all = input.flatten
filter =
  lambda do |sum, already_taken = []|
    (1..all.length).flat_map do |i|
      all.combination(i).reject do |a|
        a.any? { |h| already_taken.include?(h) }
      end.select do |a|
        a.reduce(0) { |acc, h| acc + h[:score] } == sum
      end
    end
  end
```

The only thing left would be to product all the combinations and select those without repeating tasks:

```
goals.
  map(&filter).
  reduce(&:product).
  select do |a|
    tasks = a.flatten
    tasks.uniq.size == tasks.size
  end
```

The above results in 12 possible combinations, but they have duplicates. They might be easily filtered out by sorting elements and checking for dups. That last task I would leave to you as a homework.

Comment: It took me some time to understand (I'm new!). I think I understand the code now but I'm just unclear regarding the "already_taken" array. When are you assigning it the tasks? Is that my homework? :)
Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: Ah, oh, sorry for that, it’s a leftover. Feel free to just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
require 'set'

def generate_equal_score_permutations(initial_tasks_groups)
  all_hashes = initial_tasks_groups.flatten
  scores_count = compute_scores_count(all_hashes)
  combos = generate_combos(all_hashes, scores_count)
  first, *rest = generate_permutations(scores_map, combos)
  keys = scores_count.keys    
  first.product(*rest).
        map do |p|
          h = keys.zip(p.map(&:to_enum)).to_h
          initial_tasks_groups.map do |arr|
          arr.flat_map { |g| h[g[:score]].next }
        end
      end
end
```

```
def compute_scores_count(all_hashes)
  all_hashes.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |g,h| h[g[:score]] += 1 }
end
```

```
def generate_combos(all_hashes, scores_count)
  (1..max_group_size(scores_count)).each_with_object({}) do |n,h|
    all_hashes.combination(n).each do |a|
      tot = a.sum { |h| h[:score] }
      (h[tot] ||= []) << a if scores_count.key?(tot)
    end
  end
end
```

```
def max_group_size(scores_count)
  *all_but_largest, largest = scores_count.sort.flat_map { |val,cnt| [val]*cnt }
  return all_but_largest.size if all_but_largest.sum <= largest
  tot = 0
  all_but_largest.index { |score| (tot += score) > largest }
end
```

```
def generate_permutations(scores_map, combos)
  scores_count.map { |score,count| combos[score].permutation(count).to_a }
end
```

**Example**

```
initial_tasks_groups = [
  [{task: 'Cut Tree', score: 25}, {task: 'Walk Dog', score: 10}], 
  [{task: 'Clean House', score: 10}, {task: 'Wash Floor', score: 10},
   {task: 'Call Uncle Ben', score: 15}],
  [{task: 'Wash Giraffe', score: 15}, {task: 'Burn House', score: 19}]
]
```

```
generate_equal_score_permutations(initial_tasks_groups)
  #=> [ 
       [
        [{:task=>"Cut Tree", :score=>25}, {:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10}],
        [{:task=>"Clean House", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Wash Floor", :score=>10},
         {:task=>"Call Uncle Ben", :score=>15}],
        [{:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15}, {:task=>"Burn House", :score=>19}]
       ],
       [
        [{:task=>"Cut Tree", :score=>25}, {:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10}], 
        [{:task=>"Clean House", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Wash Floor", :score=>10},
         {:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15}],
        [{:task=>"Call Uncle Ben", :score=>15}, {:task=>"Burn House", :score=>19}]
       ],
       ...
       [
        [{:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Call Uncle Ben", :score=>15},
         {:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10}],
        [{:task=>"Clean House", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Wash Floor", :score=>10},
         {:task=>"Call Uncle Ben", :score=>15}],
        [{:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15}, {:task=>"Burn House", :score=>19}]
       ],
       ...
       [
        [{:task=>"Wash Floor", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15},
         {:task=>"Wash Floor", :score=>10}],
        [{:task=>"Clean House", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10},
         {:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15}],
        [{:task=>"Call Uncle Ben", :score=>15}, {:task=>"Burn House", :score=>19}]
      ]
     ]
```

**Explanation**

The return value (array) is found to contain 84 elements, each being a modified permutation of the elements of `initial_tasks_groups`. The number 84 is not a surprise, as we can easily compute that.

There are 1, 3, 2 and 1 hashes `h` in `initial_task_groups` for which `h[:score]` equals, 25, 10, 15 and 19 respectively. The hash `h = initial_tasks_groups[0][0]` (with `h[:score]` equal `25`) can be replaced by (itself or) 1 of 3 hashes with a score of 10 and one of 2 hashes having a score of 15. Therefore, the hash with a score of 25 can appear `1 + 3*2 #=> 7` ways. The number of permutations is therefore `7*3*2*1 #=> 84`.

For the given value of `initial_tasks_groups`, the steps are as follows.

```
all_hashes = initial_tasks_groups.flatten
  #=> [{:task=>"Cut Tree", :score=>25}, {:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10},
  #    {:task=>"Clean House", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Wash Floor", :score=>10},
  #    {:task=>"Call Uncle Ben", :score=>15}, {:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15},
  #    {:task=>"Burn House", :score=>19}]
```

Next we need to know how many hashes in `all_hashes` have each of the four values of `:score`.

```
scores_count = compute_scores_count(all_hashes)
  #=> {25=>1, 10=>3, 15=>2, 19=>1}

combos = generate_combos(all_hashes, scores_count)
  #=> {25=>[
  #         [{:task=>"Cut Tree", :score=>25}],
  #         [{:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Call Uncle Ben", :score=>15}],
  #         [{:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15}],
  #         [{:task=>"Clean House", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Call Uncle Ben", :score=>15}],
  #         [{:task=>"Clean House", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15}],
  #         [{:task=>"Wash Floor", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Call Uncle Ben", :score=>15}],
  #         [{:task=>"Wash Floor", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15}]
  #       ],
  #   10=>[
  #        [{:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10}],
  #        [{:task=>"Clean House", :score=>10}],
  #        [{:task=>"Wash Floor", :score=>10}]
  #       ],
  #   15=>[
  #        [{:task=>"Call Uncle Ben", :score=>15}],
  #        [{:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15}]
  #       ],
  #   19=>[
  #        [{:task=>"Burn House", :score=>19}]
  #       ]
  #   }
```

See [Array#combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-combination) and [Enumerable#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum).

The first step in calculating `combos` is to calculate the following.

```
max_group_size(scores_count)
  #=> 2
```

We know that the score `25` equals the sum of scores `10` and `15`. The return value of `max_group_size` tells us that no value `:score` (25, say) equals the sum of more than 2 other values of `:score`. This cuts down the numbers of combinations of values of `:score` whose sums we need to examine.

Now we need an array of permutations for each of the 4 values of `:score`.

```
first, *rest = generate_permutations(scores_map, combos)
first
  #=> [
  #    [[{:task=>"Cut Tree", :score=>25}]],
  #    [[{:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Call Uncle Ben", :score=>15}]],
  #    [[{:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15}]],
  #    [[{:task=>"Clean House", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Call Uncle Ben", :score=>15}]],
  #    [[{:task=>"Clean House", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15}]],
  #    [[{:task=>"Wash Floor", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Call Uncle Ben", :score=>15}]],
  #    [[{:task=>"Wash Floor", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15}]]
  #   ]
```

```
rest
  #=> [
  #    [
  #     [
  #      [{:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10}],
  #      [{:task=>"Clean House", :score=>10}],
  #      [{:task=>"Wash Floor", :score=>10}]
  #     ],
  #     [
  #      [{:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10}],
  #      [{:task=>"Wash Floor", :score=>10}],
  #      [{:task=>"Clean House", :score=>10}]],
  #      [[{:task=>"Clean House", :score=>10}],
  #      [{:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10}],
  #      [{:task=>"Wash Floor", :score=>10}]
  #     ],
```

```
  #     [
  #      [{:task=>"Clean House", :score=>10}], [{:task=>"Wash Floor", :score=>10}],
  #      [{:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10}]], [[{:task=>"Wash Floor", :score=>10}],
  #      [{:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10}], [{:task=>"Clean House", :score=>10}]
  #     ],
  #     [
  #      [{:task=>"Wash Floor", :score=>10}],
  #      [{:task=>"Clean House", :score=>10}],
  #      [{:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10}]
  #     ]
  #    ],
  #    [
  #     [
  #      [{:task=>"Call Uncle Ben", :score=>15}],
  #      [{:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15}]],
  #      [[{:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15}],
  #      [{:task=>"Call Uncle Ben", :score=>15}]
  #     ]
  #    ],
  #    [
  #     [
  #      [{:task=>"Burn House", :score=>19}]
  #     ]
  #    ]
  #   ]
```

See [Array#permutation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-permutation).

Next we use [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-product) to compute an array that pairs each element of `first` with each element of each element of `rest`.

```
keys = scores_count.keys
  #=> [25, 10, 15, 19]
a = first.product(*rest)\
```

We'll look at just one of those 84 elements of `a`.

```
p = a[32]
  #=> [
  #    [[{:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15}]],
  #    [[{:task=>"Wash Floor", :score=>10}], [{:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10}],
  #     [{:task=>"Clean House", :score=>10}]],
  #    [[{:task=>"Call Uncle Ben", :score=>15}], [{:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15}]],
  #    [[{:task=>"Burn House", :score=>19}]]
  #   ]
```

The remaining steps for the permutation are as follows.

```
h = keys.zip(p.map(&:to_enum)).to_h
  #=> {25=>#<Enumerator: [[{:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10},
  #                        {:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15}]]:each>,
  #    10=>#<Enumerator: [[{:task=>"Wash Floor", :score=>10}],
  #                       [{:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10}],
  #                       [{:task=>"Clean House", :score=>10}]]:each>,
  #    15=>#<Enumerator: [[{:task=>"Call Uncle Ben", :score=>15}],
  #                       [{:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15}]]:each>,
  #    19=>#<Enumerator: [[{:task=>"Burn House", :score=>19}]]:each>}
```

See [Array#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-zip), [Kernel#to_enum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-to_enum) and [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h).

Lastly, we compute the modified permutation of `initial_tasks_groups` for this value of `p`.

```
initial_tasks_groups.map do |arr|
  arr.flat_map { |g| h[g[:score]].next }
end
  #=> [
  #    [{:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15},
  #     {:task=>"Wash Floor", :score=>10}],
  #    [{:task=>"Walk Dog", :score=>10}, {:task=>"Clean House", :score=>10},
  #     {:task=>"Call Uncle Ben", :score=>15}],
  #    [{:task=>"Wash Giraffe", :score=>15}, {:task=>"Burn House", :score=>19}]
```

See [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) and [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next).